# Multiple to single element mapping in Mule DataMapper

Tags: mule

[image]
I have input xml like,

```
           <EEOC>
                <EEOC>
                    <GenderCode>male</GenderCode>
                    <Ethnicity>hispanic</Ethnicity>
                    <VeteranStatus>disabled</VeteranStatus>
                </EEOC>
                <EEOC>
                    <GenderCode>male</GenderCode>
                    <Ethnicity>hispanic</Ethnicity>
                    <VeteranStatus>disabled</VeteranStatus>
                </EEOC>
            </EEOC>
```

and in the output xsd, ![enter image description here][2]tag EEOC will not repeat.

```
        <EEOC>
            <EEOC>
                <GenderCode>male</GenderCode>
                <Ethnicity>hispanic</Ethnicity>
                <VeteranStatus>disabled</VeteranStatus>
            </EEOC>
        </EEOC>
```

How can I map this in Mule Data Mapper in such case.. ?

Answer (score 0):

In the center top of the mapping (on op of the arrows) you can set how to iterate over the elements in "Element Mapping". 
It is described in [this](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/DataMapper+Concepts#DataMapperConcepts-ElementMappings) section of the documentation.

Comment: I don't see second level `EEOC` from input to first level `EEOC` mapping when  try "Element Mapping".

Comment: They appear as you create mappings, then you can remove or modify.